# how to load loactions in searchView in android studio?

Tags: android-studio, android-mapview, android-maps-v2, android-maps, android-searchmanager

I am new to map concept in android . I would like to get locations using GPS/Geo Coding and add as a suggestion for search view ,when clicking the suggestion map will show the exact location ? friends help me how do i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, you are looking for `autocompleteTextView` hooked to Google Places API. You may find [this tutorial](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-autocompletetextview-with-google-places-autocomplete-api/) & [Google Places API documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/android/autocomplete) helpful.